# Android/iOs finger print scanner used as an authentication

Tags: android, ios

I am trying to find an answer to the question of, if I have a database of fingerprints or fingerprint hashes, can I use the iOs or Android fingerprint scanners to compare the fingerprint being offered and my database and not against the local fingerprint copy? In practical application I want to enroll people into a program that uses fingerprints to secure the account and i want the exact same fingerprint to allow access to the account on the handheld device.

Thanks

Comment: The concept of keeping a database of fingerprints is a security nightmare and something that could lead to a lot of trouble. I would strongly advise against doing this. Ignoring the former issue, fingerprints cannot be extracted on iOS devices, they are embedded within dedicated hardware, so luckily the above concept is impossible.

Comment: I know there would be some "issues" with security, but storage of the data say through block chain would allow for a somewhat more secure database... however iOs not being able to comply makes most of this idea moot.

Comment: If you want to do something like this maybe think about using a certificate pair. On iOS you can generate a certificate based on touch ID and then pass the public certificate back to the API, that in turn can be safely stored. Then when it comes to authentication you would simply send a challenge to the device, the device would sign the challenge with the private certificate and send it back to the API, the server can then verify the signature with the public cert and continue authentication.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, you can't. Touch ID scanner uses on system level, you only have access to checking of validation. You can authenticate user with `LocalAutentification` framework. You can check [example](https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication) from Apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to the Android answer of this, but with iOS; **No, that is not possible.**

Apple restricts the use of Touch ID to it's own internal database per device as a security precaution.  You are not able to retrieve, store, or view any fingerprint data from a user.  If you want to use Touch ID in your app, you must implement the relevant `LocalAuthentication` framework from iOS and it will do the work for you.  Returning only a *grant* or *deny*.